# Custom deploy in QTCreator

Tags: qt, deployment, qt-creator, qt5

I am working on QTCreator (3.0.x) targeting an embedded linux device. Everything is fine except the fact that I am not able to add some custom file to deploy step...

In `.pro` file I set:

```
target.path = /home/root
INSTALLS += target
```

and I am able to deploy my executable to the remote device...

Now what if I would like to add some custom files to the deployment process?

I'd tried to add the following lines to my `.pro` file:

```
mypackage.files = /path/to/my/files/on/my/pc/*
mypackage.path = /home/root
INSTALLS += mypackage
```

but it doesn't work...

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried actual files instead of a glob string? It may not support that.

Comment: Does `mypackage.files = /path/to/my/files/on/my/pc` work?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I am going to try (now I am not at work) and I'll let you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use wildcard/glob in [the following way](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake#Replace_functions):

> $$files(glob) — Returns a list of files which match the specified glob pattern

```
mypackage.files = $$files(/path/to/my/files/on/my/pc/*)
```

But in this special case, it would be much easier to just specify the directory since you seem to be grabbing all the files anyhow, so this is what I would write personally:

```
mypackage.files = /path/to/my/files/on/my/pc
```

Comment: Laszlo, I've tried: using mypackage.files = /home/morix/Test/bin and mypackage.path = /home/root it works (all files within /home/morix/Test/bin are copied to the device) but instead of being copied to /home/root they are copied to /home/root/bin... in other words it seems that not only the files are copied to the target but even the containing directory... can I avoid that? Instead mypackage.files = files(/home/morix/bin/*) it does work... nothing is copied...

Comment: Laszlo, I found the solution... I have to use mypackage.files = $$files(/home/morix/bin/*)... in your post you've forgotten the double dollar... doing so it works like a charm! (I've edited your post to fix it). Thanks again!

Comment: @MorixDev: great, and thanks for the suggested edit. Unfortunately, there are way too many robo-reviewers on Stack Overflow, hence the ignorant rejection, but I approved the second suggested edit. Thanks again, and happy you got it working.

Comment: @LaszloPapp err... why not suggest posting a better edit comment instead? Reviewers are not expected to check the comment thread everytime the review looks incorrect. Otherwise the comments would've been shown with the review.

Comment: @JanDvorak: as already discussed, it is the task for the reviewers to check the thread before approving or rejecting logical changes. If they do not have time for that, they **should** skip the edit. They should do quality work or none. Adding a comment to check the thread is noise because I cannot imagine any other action when seeing a logical change. Suggested edits have a link to the answer by default for a reason.

Comment: @LaszloPapp it is the task of suggesters to give their edits decent comments, period. And yes, "check the comment thread" is an important part of the comment. Do you have a meta post telling you otherwise?

Comment: Wrong. It is not just about the comments, but the whole thread. Again, that is why a suggested edit has a link by default. It is not just for decoration. If someone cannot review something either because the person is incapable or does not have time, that person _really_ **should** skip the review. These reviewers would have made a bug staying in the otherwise proper answer. It is sad.